# Configure Dovecot to only let localhost connect via imap

Tags: localhost, imap, dovecot

How do I configure the Dovecot message delivery agent to only allow imap connections from localhost?

Answer (score 9):

The `listen = addr:port` config is deprecated in newer versions of dovecot.  The new way of doing things is with `service { inet_listener imap { address = ... } }`.

On my system it's in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`:

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    address = 127.0.0.1
  }
}
```

Comment: It's strange, this is supposed to be the new way to configure but my server just ignores the 'address' restriction in 10-master.conf, while another answer from year-2011 using simplistic dovecot.conf finally resolved my need...

Answer (score 7):

It's probably easiest to just listen only on localhost:

```
protocol imap {
    listen = 127.0.0.1:143
    ssl_listen = 127.0.0.1:993
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for another answer :)  I'm a bit green with all this, so what file would I make this change in?

Comment: Found it - dovecot.conf in /etc/dovecot